# Dotnet highchart visible attribute

Tags: javascript, asp.net, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I am using dotnet highchart in my project, I want to use the visible attribute of point like the following:

```
series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    visible: false
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
```

but I did not find this attribute in dotnet highchart, so how can I do it?

Comment: I'm afraid its not available in the class `Point`

Comment: is there any workaround?

Comment: Do you use any wrapper for asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link below. I think it will help you to some extent.

This hides unwanted series values.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-hide/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            visible:false 
        }, {
            data: [129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-hide/